# How to change <a href> color / remove formatting

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have put a table in a table :

```html
<th style="text-align: center; width: 50%"><img src="http://info.eoriginal.com/rs/907-BBE-942/images/date.png" /><br />

  <table style="padding-left:40px;"> 
    <tbody> 
      <tr> 
        <td bgcolor="#0EABD6" style="padding: 12px 18px 12px 18px; border-radius: 0px;" align="center"><a href="{{my.Calendar-File}}"> Add To My Calendar</a>
        </td> 
      </tr> 
    </tbody> 
  </table> 

</th>
```

but I'm not sure why the link shows like this:

[image]

How can I change the colour to white and remove the underline?

I've created the same table outside and it shows like this which is what I want:

[image]

Its also using the same code above but I created outside the existing table.

Comment: where is the css you used to format it?

Comment: @Ibu it's inline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the blue underline and change the color you need to do two things:

1. Change the `Color` for the `<a>` tag
2. Change the `text-decoration` for the `<a>` tag

So you should change the `<a>` tag from this:

```
<a href="{{my.Calendar-File}}"> Add To My Calendar</a>
```

To this:

```
<a href="{{my.Calendar-File}}" style="color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none"> Add To My Calendar</a>
```

If you apply this styling to the parent `td`, the default `a` tag css will overrule it which is why you have to place it on the `a` element itself

Answer (score 0):

```css
#cta1 a { text-decoration: none !important; color: #FFFFFF !important; }
```

```html
<div id="cta1" mktoname="cta1">
  <table style="padding-left:40px;"> 
    <tbody> 
      <tr> 
        <td bgcolor="#0EABD6" style="padding: 12px 18px 12px 18px; border-radius: 0px;" align="center"><a href="{{my.Calendar-File}}"> Add To My Calendar</a>
        </td> 
      </tr> 
    </tbody> 
  </table> 
</div>
```

Added a CSS to format the text

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
        <table style="padding-left:40px;"> 
          <tbody> 
            <tr> 
              <td style=" background-color:#0EABD6; padding :12px 18px 12px 18px; border-radius: 0px; text-decoration: none;" text-align:center><a href="{{my.Calendar-File}}"> Add To My Calendar</a>
              </td> 
            </tr> 
          </tbody> 
        </table>
```